# How do I Two-way Databind Textbox in Formview from Codebehind

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, formview

How can I take this:

`<asp:TextBox ID="Test" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Test") %>'>`

And replicate the two-way binding behavior of the formview in the codebehind?

Comment: Why can't you use a FormView?

Comment: I am using a formview.  The problem is I'm trying to create a textbox control for the formview from the codebehind, where it won't let me add the <%# Bind("Test") %> to the .Text property of the control I'm creating.

Comment: This probably isn't actually an answer, since it doesn't describe what you want to do, but what I've done in the past in this situation is to set the value of the control to the proper value from the database when I add it, and then on the OnCreate or OnUpdate events, use FindControl to find the control, and manually add its value into the object being passed to the database.